# one class svm in java

Tags: java, libsvm

Could someone show me how to use one-class SVM in Java? My problem is, I have one training Dataset and one test set and I want to use one-class svm to predict the class value.  I tried some examples on github, but they didn't work for me.

```
public static void main(String[] args){       
    DefaultDataset trainingSet = new DefaultDataset();
    LibSVM svmClassifier = new LibSVM();
    svm_parameter svmParam = new svm_parameter();
    svmParam.svm_type = svm_parameter.ONE_CLASS; //set one_class
    svmParam.kernel_type = svm_parameter.LINEAR; // set type of kernel function
    svmClassifier.setParameters(svmParam);
    OneClassSVMTest oneClassSVM = new OneClassSVMTest();
    NormalizeMidrange normalizMid = new NormalizeMidrange();

    //loadValues loads data from mysql-db
    //Double[] contains x,y,z values for example [0.123, 1.232, 0.342]
    ArrayList<Double[]> myTrainValues = oneClassSVM.loadValues(myString1);
    ArrayList<Double[]> myTestValue = oneClassSVM.loadValues(myString2);
    for(Double[] value : myTrainValues)
    {
       //toRawArray converts Double[] to double[]  
       trainingSet.add(new DenseInstance(toRawArray(value));
    }
    normalizMid.build(trainingSet);
    normalizMid.filter(trainingSet);
    svmClassifier.buildClassifier(trainingSet);

    int correct = 0, wrong = 0;
    for (Double[] d : myTestValues)
    {
        Instance inst = new DenseInstance(toRawArray(d));
        normalizMid.filter(inst);
        //is always null !?!?
        Object predictedClassValue = svmClassifier.classify(inst);
        //is always null !?!?
        Object realClassValue = inst.classValue();
        if (predictedClassValue.equals(realClassValue)) //<- Error shows up
            correct++;
        else
            wrong++;
    }
    System.out.printf("correct: %d, wrong: %d%n", correct, wrong);
}
```

As result I get `java.lang.NullPointerException` because `svmClassifier.classify(inst)` and `inst.classValue()` always return `null`. 
So I tried something else:

```
    Map<Object, Double> classDistributionMap;
    for (Double[] a : myTestValue)
    {
        Instance inst = new DenseInstance(toRawArray(a));
        normalizMid.filter(inst);
        classDistributionMap = svmClassifier.classDistribution(inst);
        Set<Map.Entry<Object, Double>> entrySet = classDistributionMap.entrySet();
        for (Entry<Object, Double> entry : entrySet)
            System.out.println(entry.getValue());

    }
```

As results there only `1.0`. I can't explain why there is only `1.0`

Comment: Which library are you using? can you please add a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

The SVM classifier function

y=f(x)

where y = {1, -1} y=1.0 means data belong to the class and -1.0 means data belong to another class.

x is the vector of 1 by n where n= number of attributes of each data sets where is the class of the data. from the above, it might means that all the data are classified to the same class as the expected class which 1.0; Data belonging to another class will be -1.0.

So, from your observation, it might means that the data sets are all classified to the same class

Comment: Thank u for the explanation. Can u tell me something about the `NullpointerException`in the code above?

Comment: NullPointerException occurs when there is no assigned value to the query object. There is need to know the return type of those method or better still, read the documentation of the method invoke. This will help you to know what they are to return. Mostly, it has to be that you need to have supply the classValue via a get Method in the libSvm. Failure to supply the value before querying will leads to NullPointerException.